# qmake: detect whether the kit uses a static or dynamic Qt version

Tags: qt, qmake, static-linking, dynamic-linking

Is there a way to check whether the active kit uses a static or dynamic Qt build? Something like this:

```
contains(SOME_QMAKE_VARIABLE, STATIC_QT_BUILD) {
  message("static build detected!")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what I'd like but still somewhat of a solution, provided the rather typical inclusion of the word "static" in the current qt installation path:

```
QtPath = $$clean_path($$[QT_INSTALL_PREFIX]/)
IsQtStatic = $$find(QtPath, "static")
isEmpty(IsQtStatic) {
  message(qt is DYNAMIC)
} else {
  message(qt is STATIC)
}
```